# How to find a replacemen car stereo display

Tags: audio

I am trying to replace the radio module on my Qashqai+2 2010. I have found some online stores, where you can get radios, but no information about which radio is compatible with what car. Can I just take any Double Din Radio and expect it to work? What about the controls on the steering wheel?

Comment: If you look for the aftermarket Pioneers, Kenwoods etc you will see that the steering wheel control adaptors are available separately...

Comment: Oh, thx for the tip. And for the size, I just take any double din right?